# this context not working in my waypoints.js snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been messing around with [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/) for a while now(jQuery.waypoints) and basically i am trying to use this library to add animations to children of a certain container element and i do it in the following fashion:

```
    var waypoints = $('#collection').waypoint(function() {
            $('#collection .col-md-3').each(function(){
                        var $this = $(this);

                        var elem_class = $(this).attr('data-anim-name');
                        var elem_delay = $(this).attr('data-anim-delay');

                        $this.css({
                            '-webkit-animation-delay' : elem_delay,
                            '-moz-animation-delay' : elem_delay,
                            'animation-delay' : elem_delay
                        });

                        $this.addClass(elem_class);

            });
    }, {
        offset: '25%'
    });
```

notice the selection i am making inside the function i am passing to way points :

```
$('#collection .col-md-3').each(function(){
```

now the above code works fine, but when i re-wrote the above code to :

```
$('.col-md-3' , this).each(function(){
```

my code does't work , as far as i am concerned my code is perfectly correct , because `this` would be indeed `#collection` . so why does't the code work ?

My HTML structure looks something like below :

```
<section id="collection">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</section>
```

can somebody explain why the usage of this does't work in my code at all ? what am i missing ?

Thank you.

Ale-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most jQuery functions, you'd be right - you could use `this` as your context for the 2nd parameter, it's usually bound to the element being worked on.  However, with waypoints the callback function has a different object bound as `this`.  Here's an example gleaned from their website:

[image: waypoint this object]

So within a waypoints callback handler, you can instead use `this.element` as your context:

```
var waypoints = $('#collection').waypoint(function() {
    $('.col-md-3', this.element).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //etc
```

Looking through the rest of the documentation, I can't find a direct reference to this behaviour/functionality in the API, so it may or may not be something you can rely on to work in future versions, but rather just a side effect of how it's been implemented.

Comment: thanks alot for taking the trouble , just one more question , what did you look up in the console ?

Comment: I stuck a break point in one of their handlers, then just typed "this" in the console to see what it was

Comment: did you use chrome ? sorry for the noob question , but how did you insert the breakpoint ?

Comment: Yes - it's Chrome.  To insert a breakpoint, find the code you're interested in on the "sources" tab, and click on the linenumber you want to break at.  If you've not used the dev tools too much, [there is loads of documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), including specifics on [JavaScript debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)